# can i write a text over hidden text and if the hidden text is visible by javascript my text will move right to hidden text ..which is visible now..?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website for a company and the company wants that the user first should fill all the information and he should proceed then...

For that I made a form with this code:

```
    <form action="Owners Infoback.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()"  method="post" name="enquiry" id="" class="form-body-02">
    <ul>
        <li style="overflow:hidden;">
          <label for="Name" class="l1">1. Name of owner:<br />
         <p>(If more than one seperate using comma.</br> Eg. A,B,C )<br /></p></label>
         <div id="nameOfOwnerError" style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; margin-left:20px;">*</div>
         <input name="Name_of_owner" type="text" class="textarea-bk-02" id=""  value="<?php echo "{$row[0]}";?>" style="border:none; width:330px; margin-left:14px; margin-top:15px; height:20px;"/>

        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="Name" class="l1">2. Name of company:<br /><p>(Enter name registered)</p></label>
          <div id="nameOfOwnerCompany" style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; margin-left:20px;">*</div>
          <input name="Name_of_company_registered" type="text" class="textarea-bk-02" id=""  value="<?php echo "{$row[1]}";?>" style="border:none; width:330px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:13px; height:20px;"/>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="Name" class="l1">3. Address:<p>(Write your own manufacturer address)</p></label>
          <div id="nameOfOwnerAddress"style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; margin-left:20px;">*</div>
          <input name="Owner_address" type="text" class="textarea-bk-02" id=""  value="<?php echo "{$row[2]}";?>" style="border:none; width:330px; height:20px; margin-left:13px; margin-top:13px;"/>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="Name" class="l1">4. Email id:<p></p></label>
          <div id="nameOfOwnerEmail" style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; margin-left:20px;">*</div>
          <input name="Owner_Email_id" type="text" class="textarea-bk-02" id=""  value="<?php echo "{$row[3]}";?>" style="border:none; width:330px; margin-left:13px; margin-top:13px; height:20px;"/>
        </li>


        <li>
        <div id="nameOfOwnerError1" style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; position:relative"> Name of owner,</div>
        <div id="nameOfOwnerCompany1" style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; position:relative"> Name of company,</div>
        <div id="nameOfOwnerAddress1" style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; position:relative"> Address,</div>
        <div id="nameOfOwnerEmail1" style="visibility:hidden;color:red; display:inline; position:relative"> valid Email id</div>
        <input name="Save" type="submit"  class="send-btns-02 right" value="save" style="margin-top:5px;" >
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
```

and in the header part, i wrote javascript as:-

```
     <script>
     function validateForm()
{
var y=true;
var x=document.forms["enquiry"]["Name_of_owner"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerError").style.visibility="visible";  
    document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerError1").style.visibility="visible"; 
    y= false;
  }
  else
  { document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerError").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerError1").style.visibility="hidden";
  }

  x=document.forms["enquiry"]["Name_of_company_registered"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
      document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerCompany").style.visibility="visible";
      document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerCompany1").style.visibility="visible";
      y= false;
  }
  else
  {document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerCompany").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerCompany1").style.visibility="hidden";
  }

 x=document.forms["enquiry"]["Owner_address"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
     document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerAddress").style.visibility="visible";
     document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerAddress1").style.visibility="visible";
    y= false;
  }
   else
  {document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerAddress").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerAddress1").style.visibility="hidden";
  }

 x=document.forms["enquiry"]["Owner_Email_id"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerEmail").style.visibility="visible";
  document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerEmail1").style.visibility="visible";
  y= false;
  }
  else
  {document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerEmail").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerEmail1").style.visibility="hidden";
  }
  return y;
}
</script>
```

I am getting my screen (as you can see in the image) after running the script when alternate fields are filled... It doesn't print continuous red text, it is printing the space of hidden fields too... How can I get the continuous text of empty fields?

Sorry as I am a new user so my image is not visible, but in the image I am showing when I fill only the name of the owner and address. It prints the name of the company and valid Email ID in red, but in the middle of these there is a vacant space of hidden address text. How can I remove that?

Comment: Please put together a full example on http://jsfiddle.net so others can play around with it

Comment: To get your image to work, simply don't put four spaces at the start of the line.  You had the syntax correct, but putting four spaces at the start of a line means "print this line as literal code", so it was printed as sample code, not processed as a Markdown image.

Comment: it is still giving error as:- We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: Why are you using php while you are validating your form with javascript?

Comment: frm java script only i am seeing ..if any field is empty...jst fill that.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
.style.visibility="visible";
```

use

```
.style.display = '';
```

and for

```
.style.visibility="hidden";
```

use

```
.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: i am already using display:inline, i can not use that twice...another solution..?

Comment: I am not asking to change in your html, I am asking this change in your javascript method, like for         document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerError").style.visibility="visible";      use     document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerError").style.display = 'inline';       and for hidden use:     document.getElementById("nameOfOwnerError").style.display = 'none';

Comment: i changed my div tag intially as:- <div id="nameOfOwnerError1" style="display:none;color:red; position:relative"> Name of owner,</div>.. but it is still visible..not hidden..??

Comment: display:none property will make the div hidden.

Comment: it is not hiding.....i wrote my div code above....if there is any mistake in that..plzz tell me...??

Comment: in the form code, remove visibility property from div tags and instead use display property and than in javascript use display property to show and hide.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jsfiddle for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_katti/cLjAN/

Just check out if that's the desired output.

You have mis-placed php script inside the value attribute of each input tag.
And your border:none makes the border of the input disappear. I corrected that. And I assume that u have used a div to just get a red * behind every input to signify it is compulsory field.

Have I got it right?